# mysql and unicode characters

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I would like use Korean in my mysql table but it's unreadable whn I display all rows
for examples

```
Select * from table where 사용자 = 김 민 ​​히 ;
```

Also I see my table only odd characters.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things:

1. While creating your table, ensure it's charset is UTF-8
2. Before working with results, do this `set names utf8;`